# IF Statement in Woocommerce product category

Tags: php, wordpress, if-statement

I've been trying for a while now to try and make the code below work but  i think im missing something obvious.

I'm using Woocommerce and i'm basically looking to add a php file into the category based on criteria

1. is in the tshirts category
2. is in the tshirt category and the tshirt is tagged for men
3. is in the tshirt category and the tshirt is tagged for women

3 templates, 3 scenarios.

I'm sure there is a more elegent way to do this. Apologies for the rookie question but i really did look this up.

```
<?php
    $tshirt = (has_term('tshirt', 'product_cat'));
    $men = (has_term('men', 'product_tag'));
    $women = (has_term('women', 'product_tag'));

    if (($tshirt = '1') && ($men = '') && ($women = '')){
    include ('template1.php'); 
    }
    elseif (($tshirt = '1') && ($men = '1') && ($women = '')) {
    include ('template2.php'); 
    }

    elseif (($tshirt = '1') && ($men = '') && ($women = '1')) {
    include ('template3.php');  

    }

?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In all of your `if` `else if` conditions you need to use comparison parameter `==` and not assignment operator `=`

```
if (($tshirt = '1') && ($men = '') && ($women = '')){
```

should be

```
if (($tshirt == '1') && ($men == '') && ($women == '')){
```

same to be continued over `else if` statement

Comment: I cant believe is was that easy....I have another issue in that the main category is being tagged with women and I don't know why but i don't believe that is relating to this question.

Comment: In 5 minutes (when allowed)  i will do :).